# How to drive this 115VDC coil through a 480VAC system

Tags: coil

Below there's the electrical specification of a coil I'm using. It says it can be supplied 115VDC. If I were working with a 120V system, that would be OK. However, I'm trying to use this coil in a 480 VAC application. The 480VAC gets rectified for a SMPS which feeds a microcontroller. The idea is to drive this coil from the micro. It would only receive like a ~30 ms pulse under certain conditions. It's no intended to keep it ON all the time. The problem I'm facing is with the voltage. 480VAC rectified gets around 680VDC peak. And that's probably too high, and will require a high voltage FET. Is there a way to drive this coil so it doesn't see the full voltage? It can surely be quickly overdriven, but not from ~700V I think.

[image]

Comment: A tiny transformer?

Comment: For many off : contact the mfg and ask if they can rewind it for 680V. For one off : at lower voltages I'd say, rewind it yourself. (but at 680V, maintaining insulation is not trivial)

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me but Not sure if you know... you can"t drive that off 120VAC, and if you rectify to DC you"ll get 170VDC

Easiest brute force and cheapest solution IMO is make a voltage divider out of it.

Rectify your 480VAC....That'll give you 670VDC.   Not sure if you need a capacitor.  If you do, you can get to 670V rating with two series lower value caps of 450V each.   These are very easily obtained, tube guitar amps all have them.   Put a 100k 1/2 watt resistor across each to balance them.

The coil is 290 ohms.   At 120V it will consume 120/290=410mA

Once the solenoid hits the end of travel, the only impedance is the wire resistance.

If you place a resistor of  1330 ohms, in series with the solenoid, you'll effectively drive it at 120V.   This is the voltage divider rule.

Vout=Vin * R1 / ( R2 + R1)   where R1 is your 290 ohm solenoid.

The resistor has to handle the power.   1330 * 410mA ^ 2 = 220W.    You need to nail 1340 of course.   1k 200W in series with 270ohm 50W  are easily located and should do the trick    200W is alot but you'd be surprised how cheap power resistors are.   Example :
https://www.ebay.com/itm/184256004229

Note those have to be bolted to something big and metal to sink that much heat away.

One could argue that since youre only driving 30ms, perhaps such high power handling isn't necessary because it takes time to heat up.   However, stuff happens and if it somehow got stuck on, well.....

One might also think 200W is alot.  It is.  But your solenoid will drop 50W.   200 is only 4x more.    And its only for 30 ms!

If your 480VAC source can't deliver that much power without choking or glitching your microcontroller, you can get fancy and find a suitable SMPS.   Or see if you can source a 4:1 transformer and rectify that.    Your supply will have to still source 50w, so those two options aren't gonna be cheap.

If this sounds like something you'd like to try, hit me up and I'll draw you a schematic.